# PHP loops and Nth iterations

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, twitter-bootstrap-3

Assuming I have the following links in an array like so:

```
<?php 
  $links = array(
    array("Link 1", "link_href"),
    array("Link 2", "link_href"),
    array("Link 3", "link_href"),
    array("Link 4", "link_href"),
    array("Link 5", "link_href"),
    array("Link 6", "link_href"),
    array("Link 7", "link_href"),
    array("Link 8", "link_href")
  );
?>
```

How I can achieve the following HTML output using a PHP loop where a div class of `row` wraps inner elements every fourth anchor output as below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
    <a href="#">Link 6</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
    <a href="#">Link 7</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
    <a href="#">Link 8</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Add counter and count till 4.

Comment: you also don't `Need` to wrap them into rows of 4 ... especially since you are using the -xs- size

Comment: Sorry @cmorrissey you're right. The bootstrap classes where just as an example for clarity but we are actually using multiple bootstrap classes -sm- -md- and -lg-

Comment: @u_mulder Is there any chance you could provide an example? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_chunk()` to split your array into arrays of size 4, then iterate row wise over data using `foreach`.

```
$links = array(
  array("Link 1", "link_href1"),
  array("Link 2", "link_href2"),
  array("Link 3", "link_href3"),
  array("Link 4", "link_href4"),
  array("Link 5", "link_href5"),
  array("Link 6", "link_href6"),
  array("Link 7", "link_href7"),
  array("Link 8", "link_href8"),
  array("Link 9", "link_href9"),
);

$divsPerRow = 4;
foreach(array_chunk($links,$divsPerRow) as $row) {
  echo "<div class=\"row\">\n";
  foreach($row as $col) {
    list($label,$link) = $col;
    echo "\t<div class=\"col-xs-3 col-sm-6\">\n\t\t<a href=\"$link\">$label</a>\n\t</div>\n";
  }
  echo "</div>\n";
}
```

Can even handle scenarios where `count($links)` is not a multipe of 4. Just set `$divsPerRow` to the desired value.

Output:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
        <a href="link_href1">Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
        <a href="link_href2">Link 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
        <a href="link_href3">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
        <a href="link_href4">Link 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
        <a href="link_href5">Link 5</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
        <a href="link_href6">Link 6</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
        <a href="link_href7">Link 7</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
        <a href="link_href8">Link 8</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">
        <a href="link_href9">Link 9</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Live example can be found at: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0075882e8abeda68ed1807b6d738714145b302e8

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using a 12 column grid (probably bootstrap). If might be helpful to not only put things in the proper divs, but also have the ability to change the style using php variables. Here is a little code snip that might help you:

```
$colSize = 3;
$colPrefix = "col-xs";
$numPerRow = 12/$colSize;

for($ii = 0; $ii<count($links); $ii++) {
    if ($ii % $numPerRow == 0) {
        echo "<div class='row'>\n";
    }
        echo "\t<div class='$colPrefix-$colSize'>\n";
        echo "\t\t<a href='{$links[$ii][1]}'>{$links[$ii][0]}</a>\n";
        echo "\t</div>\n";

    if ($ii % $numPerRow == $numPerRow-1 || $ii == count($links)-1) {
        echo "</div>\n";
    }
}
```

Naturally, this would just be a starting point. If you wanted to hard-code some of the html classes instead of using PHP variables, it should be easy enough to change. The important part is that you can set `$numPerRow` to whatever you need and the code will work from there.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much for this answer - it's a great starting point and I like the idea of passing the class names into variables.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try a foreach loop:

```
$i = 0;  
foreach ($links as $link) {  
    if ($i == 0) {  
        echo '<div class="row">';  
    }  
    #...  
    echo '<a href="' . $link[1] . '">' . $link[0] . '</a>';  
    #...  
    ++$i;  
    if ($i == 4) {  
        echo '</div>';  
        $i = 0;  
    }  
}  
if ($i != 0) {  
    echo '</div>';  
}
```